# Health monitoring not working

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, health-monitoring

I am trying to set up health monitoring on an IIS 6/ASP.NET 2 application running on Windows Server 2003.

What I want to do for a first step, is getting the Application Lifetime Events in addition to the default events (as specified in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config).

On my dev machine running IIS 7 as NetworkService on Windows 7 that works fine.

On the IIS 6 machine, the default events still get logged to the event log but the additional life time events do not. In addition, **no events regarding misconfiguration get logged or shown**. Also, using a **SimpleMailProvider instead of the event logging does not produce results**.

It looks like it is just ignoring my settings. I have tried many variations of settings - even copied all the global healthmonitoring settings into the application web.config - but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the settings I added to the web.config:

```
<healthMonitoring enabled="true">
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <add name="All Errors Default" eventName="All Errors" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Critical" />
        <add name="Application Lifetime Events Default" eventName="Application Lifetime Events" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Critical" />
        <add name="Failure Audits Default" eventName="Failure Audits" provider="EventLogProvider" profile="Critical" />
    </rules>
</healthMonitoring>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that your account `NetworkService` does not have access to the registry - which is required by the logging framework.

Grant read/write access to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application

and see if that helps.